# iOS Game Center Peer to Peer using Game Kit

Tags: iphone, gamekit, game-center

I would like some confirmation before looking into the APIs deeply. Does Game Center let developers build an app so users can connect and interact with each other seamlessly ?

I mean, if I wanted to build a simple game, like a multiplayer quizz. I want people to look for each other on game center, go to a "game room" and answer the same quizz questions, the fastest winning.

As a developer point of vue, what will be required to my app ? Do I have call back like

player:(Player *)player didSendData:(NSData *)data

so I can check who gets the good answer and broadcast a message to everyone (to update their screen)

I know I could RTFM, I just want to know if "yes" that's basically the goal, or "no" you won't be able to do that with game center.

Thanks !

Comment: GameCenter doesn't. The GameKit framework does I believe (Which GameCenter is part of).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, Yes, you can do that. You can use Game Center to connect users using Apple's matchmaking services. This allows you to send push notifications to other Game Center users to invite them to connect. There's also the underlying GameKit framework (which Game Center uses) that allows you to create an ad-hoc network between devices in proximity over BlueTooth or Wifi. You can also dive into a bit of hardcore C and use Bonjour to connect devices. I use both peer-to-peer and Game Center connectivity in my game [Cee-lo](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cee-lo/id390557478?mt=8).

Comment: So to be clear, I can make two or more people play the same network game, even if one is in Seattle, and the others in Paris ? I connect them through Game Center, and either use p2p or make on player be the server ?

Comment: From Seattle -> Paris, your best bet would be using Game Center, yes. I've played Cee-lo with my friend in Chicago while I was in Seattle. The Peer to Peer stuff is shorter range. "In the same room" for Bluetooth and on the same wifi network (so the distance is pretty decent) for Wifi.

Comment: You could also write your own connection services using something like http://www.smartfoxserver.com/ but that would be costly and much more complex than just using Apple's Game Center client.